# msys2 shell can't find python even though it exists

Tags: bash, windows-10, msys2

If I use 'which' to find python it comes back:

```
$ which -a python.exe
which: no python.exe in (C:/msys32/mingw32/bin;/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/opt/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
```

but if I do a 'dir' of `C:/msys32/mingw32/bin` python files are found:

```
$ dir C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/py*
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/pydoc
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python.exe
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python2.7.exe
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python2.7-config
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python2.exe
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python2-config
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python2w.exe
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python-config
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python-config.sh
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/python-config-u.sh
```

This is under Windows 10. Any ideas please?

Comment: `C:/msys32/mingw32/bin;/usr/local/bin` uses the wrong delimiter and the wrong path style. It should be `/c/msys32/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin`, right? It's rather confusing that Cygwin / msys2 will work with Windows style paths -- sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the bash shell can not locate the python executable. To solve the issue a change should be done inside the ***.bashrc*** file.

The following configuration should be done inside the ***.bashrc*** file.

```
# python and pip alias
alias python="c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python3.8.exe"
alias pip="c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/pip3.exe"
```

More detailed information can be found on this [blogpost](http://orthodoxpirate.blogspot.com/2020/12/msys2-python-command-not-found-how-to.html).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to simply log off and log in again. This is necessary when updating ENVs

Comment: That didn't help I'm afraid. I had already tried restarting MSYS2, to no avail.